# JavaScript Promise Declaration Difference

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript learner and have an issue about Promises.

When I use function `resolve` of `Promise` object, I got no errors as expected. Like :

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
```

However, when I use following declaration:

```
var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'foo');
});
promise2.resolve(4)
```

Isn't this the same thing? Or if `promise2` is also a `Promise` class object, why do I get an error like :

```
TypeError: promise2.resolve is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Comment: Promise.resolve() is a static function of the Promise class. A promise instance, like promise2, does Not have a resolve() method, since resolve() should be called inside the promise, as you show with the setTimeout().

Comment: Got the point thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 9):

No, they are not the same thing.

The `resolve` method on the `Promise` (with a capital `P`) constructor function creates a **new** promise and immediately resolves it.

Existing promises don't have a `resolve` method. They can only be resolved by calling the function passed to the first argument of the function you pass to the `Promise` constructor function.

---

> Or if promise2 is also a Promise class object, why do I get an error like

`promise2` is an **instance** of `Promise`.

`Promise` is a constructor function used to create promises, it isn't a promise itself.

Consider the difference between a motor car and a Ford factory.

Answer (score 3):

They are different things.

`Promise.resolve(3);` creates a new promise which is already resolved.

`new Promise()` also creates a new promise, but you need to call `then` on `promise2` instead of `resolve` to be able to get the desired output.